# Error establishing a database connection - Ubuntu WordPress on 14.04

Tags: wordpress, apache, digital-ocean

Today I have started to see in my website this message **"Error establishing a database connection"**, so I was investigating and I saw this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-wordpress-from-xml-rpc-attacks-on-ubuntu-14-04?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=wordpress_ubuntu_tut&utm_content=no_image) related and I have tried to implement it but its not working for me I still getting the same issue and I have no clue why.

Below is what I have implemented from the article:

For Apache on Ubuntu 14.04, edit the configuration file with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Add the highlighted lines below between the  tags.

```
Apache VirtualHost Config
<VirtualHost>
…    
    <files xmlrpc.php>
      order allow,deny
      deny from all
    </files>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close this file when you are finished.

Restart the web server to enable the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

What is weird is when I restart the droplet the website works for a couple of seconds so.. I cant figure out how to fix it.

> Droplet details:  512 MB Memory / 20 GB Disk / LON1 - Ubuntu WordPress
>   on 14.04

Comment: is mysql running? `sudo service mysql status` what do you get?

Comment: mysql stop/waiting @DustyBoshoff

Comment: your mysql has stopped. try `sudo service mysql start` see if that generates a error on screen

Comment: after execute that its working for a couple of seconds and then happen the same.. @DustyBoshoff

Comment: when it stops again check the `cat /var/log/mysql/error.log` file to see what caused the stop, or paste the output to pastebin and share the link here. you can also open another terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log` while in the 1st terminal you start it, this will scroll the error log in realtime in the 2nd terminal while you start and stop the service.

Comment: I have tried to execute the `sudo service mysql start` and now says `job failed to start`, anyways here is the error.log http://pastebin.com/BMkVXDP1 @DustyBoshoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your logs show MySQL battling to allocate memory
`Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`

Here's something you can do to get past it.

**Add a Swap file**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.dat bs=1024 count=512M
mkswap /swap.dat
swapon /swap.dat
```

**Reduce the memory footprint of MySQL**
Edit /etc/my.cnf, and add the following line under the [mysqld] heading.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
```

Comment: what does mean add a ´swap file´, sorry but I'm not familiar with it. @ DustyBoshoff

Comment: I have used this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 and it's working. thanks!

Comment: adding swap is another way to add "Virtual Memory" to your machine, in Windows it's called pagefile I think. To MySQL it looks like your machine has 1GB RAM, when infact it only has 512MB physical and 512MB virtual. You can see the consumption by typing `free -h`